# No way to respond to message on careers?

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

Just got a message on careers, but the employer didn't include any contact information they simply said:

> Interested? Reply to this message and send over a coding sample.

I clicked 'interested'. but unless I'm missing something I can't reply directly through the careers site. I looked around and I can't find **any** way to contact the employer.

Is this a bug? An omission? and how can I have someone @stackoverflow let this employer know about the problem.

Comment: I wonder how many of us got this `You = Django ninja`? Who say "I"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I have the possibility to search for CV's and hire users of SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198237/do-i-have-the-possibility-to-search-for-cvs-and-hire-users-of-so), see comment on the question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293/3648282

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other way around. They're supposed to contact *you* -- **they are emailed your mailing address when you click "I'm Interested"**.

Although it is odd for them not to include any contact information in their message. We're thinking of putting a "JOEL'S PRO TIPS" help section for the employers next to the message composition box.

Edit: we now have quite a bit of help text next to the employer message composition box -- and it is possible in your response to enter a message back to the employer, such as, "WTF?" (if necessary)

Comment: Ok, that answers the question. But I think it needs to be made obvious that this is happening when I click "I'm interested". 

Perhaps a message like:

"You responded you were interested in this message. We have sent your contact information to the employer, they should be in touch with you shortly"