# Do I have the possibility to search for CV's and hire users of SO?

Tags: support, job-offers

I'm looking for some php programmers to hire and would like to know if I might have the possibility to seach CV's of candidates who are looking for a job.

Is there any function / setup within SO that give this possibility?

Comment: Other than the [Careers site](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/), you would have to go through their About Me sections in their profiles. There is no such explicit functionality available within Stack Overflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let's close \[jobs\] questions!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377689/282094), because this feature is recently discontinued:   https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can Search here on [careers site of Stack Overflow](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)

You can also go to [Top Users of php](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/topusers) and check each profile's "About Me" section to see if the corresponding person has contact details or has interest in jobs.

### Update of April 2022

The Stack Overflow careers site has [shut down](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story). Use the second method described above to search for good employees to hire.